# preg_match to match a list of words but not some

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to create a fairly simple regular expression to use with preg_match() used to check user agent strings for possible web crawlers/spiders.

For example, right now I am using something similar to this:

`preg_match("/(bot|search|web|slurp|crawl)/i")`

which seems to be successfully matching user agents that contain something like "googlebot" or "webcrawler".

However, the problem I am having is that this also matches when the user agent contains something as common as "webkit".

What modifications would be necessary to prevent specific words such as "webkit" from being matched? I have very little understanding of regular expressions and have spent hours trying various combinations based off answers to other questions and have had no success so far.

Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do you have a full list of the words you wish to exclude? BTW I'm not asking to see the list :)

Comment: `preg_match("/\b(bot|search|web|slurp|crawl)\b/ui")`

Comment: If I could exclude a list of specific words that would be ideal, as I may come across others that need to be excluded.

Comment: @l̕aͨŵƦȆ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝ƞCͭ̏ȇƇhƐȓ0nè That seems to solve the problem with "webkit" being matched but now it does not match other user agents that I'm comparing it against such as "FastCrawler 3.0.X (crawler@1klik.dk) - http://www.1klik.dk"

Comment: You must provide either the full list of elments to be matched, or the full list of elmeents to be excluded... In the meanwhile, this expression should help `(bot|search|web(?!k)|slurp|crawl)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to exclude a certain list of words, you can combine two lookaheads:

```
(?!webkit|robot)(?=bot|search|web|slurp|crawl)
```

Apparently the first part would be your exclusion list. This would match "**web**" but not "**webkit**"

A small note on the syntax. (?!regex) is negative lookahead and (?=regex) is a positive lookahead (non-consuming regular expression). You can [read more upon it here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html). 
In short, a lookahead means "match regex expr but after that continue matching at the original match-point."

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work perfectly! I'm sure I tried using ?! but must have been using it incorrectly.

Comment: @user2716559 Welcome! I personally like to quick test my expressions in online regex editors like http://www.rubular.com/ . I find it very convenient.